# Mockito thenReturn returns same instance

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I have this in Mockito:

```java
when(mockedMergeContext.createNewEntityOfType(IService.class)).thenReturn(new ServiceMock());
```

The `createNewEntityOfType` method should always return a new `ServiceMock` instance but it returns twice the same reference.

Why the `thenReturn` method doesn't return new `ServiceMock`?

Comment: Try stubbing with a [callback](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#11)

Answer (score 63, accepted):

The `thenReturn` method will always return what is passed to it. The code `new Servicemock()` is being executed prior to the call to `thenReturn`. The created `ServiceMock` is then being passed to `thenReturn`. Therefore `thenReturn` has a absolute instance of `ServiceMock` not a creation mechanism.

If you need to provide an new instance, use [thenAnswer](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/stubbing/OngoingStubbing.html#thenAnswer%28org.mockito.stubbing.Answer%29)

```
when(mockedMergeContext.createNewEntityOfType(IService.class))
  .thenAnswer(new Answer<IService>() {
     public IService answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) {
        return new ServiceMock();
     }
   });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for saving my day :)

Comment: Exactly true, I was looking every where configuring java thread pool mechanism to make my unit test pass, in vain ! You saved me a lot of time, mockito was the faulty.

Answer (score 17):

In Java 8 with Lambdas you can just use

```
when(mockedMergeContext.createNewEntityOfType(IService.class)).thenAnswer(invocation -> new ServiceMock());
```

So just replace `.thenReturn(new MyMock());`

with `.thenAnswer(invocation -> new MyMock());`

Comment: Thank you for keeping this simple for people coming from google search and not trying to get a lecture :)

Answer (score 10):

You might want to refactor that into different statements to understand why that happens.

```
Service svc = new ServiceMock();
when(mockedMergeContext.createNewEntityOfType(IService.class)).thenReturn( svc );
```

Do you see now why it doesn't work? :)

It's always returning the instance hold in svc, it won't re-evaluate `new ServiceMock()` each time that the method is invoked.