# Mocking Calendar.getInstance static method multiple times in a method

Tags: java, unit-testing, calendar, powermockito

I am currently using JMockito/PowerMock so that I can mock the return value of a static method, in this case, Calendar.getInstance().
My issue is very similar to this, but not quite:
[PowerMocking static does not return expected object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14456377/powermocking-static-does-not-return-expected-object)

I have also checked various other similar topics but none of them quite falls into my context. Currently, I have a code that like this:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
//modifies this instance
.....
.....
//then there is another call:
cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
....
....
```

What the logic does is not important here. When I have tried testing this block of method, I have expectation like so:

```
Calendar myOwn = //whatever
when(Calendar.getInstance()).thenReturn(myOwn);
```

So during test what happens testing is that in the first call of `Calendar.getInstance()` it manages to successfully get `myOwn` object which is what I expect. And obviously, the method then does some modification to this object.

**However**, while debugging, when the next call `Calendar.getInstance()` happens later, the variable `cal2` seems to get the modified version of `myOwn` object from before. I would have thought that it would get the *original* `myOwn` calendar object but it doesn't.

I have also tried rebuilding the expectation to this (because there is a total of two `getInstance()` calls, at least in this method):

```
when(Calendar.getInstance()).thenReturn(myOwn).theReturn(myOwn);
```

but no luck. Then I thought whether this was an issue of variable getting passed by reference due to it being static however, the following output is valid and perfectly logical too as I tested it in isolation.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
System.out.println(cal.getTime()); //prints current date object (as expected)

cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2017);
System.out.println(cal.getTime()); //prints modified timestamp of 2017 (as expected)

//new instance
Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
System.out.println(cal2.getTime()); //still prints current date object (as expected)
```

I can easily fix my test if I clone the second instance of calendar object in code from previous before it gets modified. But this involve modifying existing source code which I can't as it's quite a legacy code.

So what have I done wrong in my unit test with this static method? I have also tried testing with JMockit and still get the same issue. Pretty sure it's something obvious but cannot figure it out. Thank you for your time.

Comment: the [spock testing framework](https://code.google.com/p/spock/) (which I love) can do this out of the box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `myOwn` is the same instance.  The `thenReturn` code is only run once at the start of your test.  You've created only the one `Calendar` object, and Mockito is simply returning it twice.  So if it's modified the first time `getInstance` is called, that modified object will be returned the second time it's called.

Try instead:

```
Calendar myOwn = //whatever
Calendar myOwnSecond = //whatever - new instance though, not the same as myOwn!!
when(Calendar.getInstance()).thenReturn(myOwn).thenReturn(myOwnSecond);
```

If you want to return a new calendar instance each time (so for times when you want `x` number of Calendar instances), and you don't need to hold on to the calendar instance for your test, you'll want to use `thenAnswer`.  Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8227405/mockito-thenreturn-returns-same-instance) for details.  Or just use:

```
when(Calendar.getInstance()).thenAnswer((invocation)->new MyCalendar());
```

or Java 7

```
when(Calendar.getInstance())
    .thenAnswer(new Answer<Calendar>() {
        Calendar answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) {
            return // however you're instantiating it
    }
});
```

Comment: I am sending a clone of previous `Calendar` object to the second `thenReturn` method but still same issue.

Comment: How are you cloning it?  Are you making a proper deep copy?  You haven't accidentally got an additional call to `getInstance()` in there?  If you call `.getInstance()` three times, then `.thenReturn` will `myOwnSecond` twice at the end.  What are you doing with the calendar instances after you return them in the test code?  You may be better of using `thenAnswer` instead if you're not using them for testing.